# str_replace for a utf8 string

Tags: php, string

`str = "asd€aaa";`

`$str = str_replace("€","",$str);`

Not replacing the € sign for some reason.

I have `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` set up at the top of the file (which is saved in UTF-8).

The string originates from a MySQL db, so I also have these set:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci'");
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

This means the string coming from the database and the search string are not in the same encoding and are hence not recognized as the same character. Make sure *your source code file* is saved in UTF-8 as well.